# Getting Exception while Connecting to Internet in android

Tags: android

I am use OpenHttpConnection(URL) method to connect internet in my android application. But getting "java.io.IOException:Error Conneting".How i can avoid this. Permissions in android manifest had given.
Please help me .
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step #1: Make certain your INTERNET permission is in the correct place.

Step #2: Make certain your device or emulator has Internet access. For example, if you are using the emulator, and you see that you have zero bars of signal strength in the status bar icon, your emulator does not have Internet access. That will happen if the emulator was unable to detect Internet access when you started up the emulator.

Step #3: Make certain that whatever you are trying to connect to is actually up and running.